# JavaScript data post to PHP, why data not receive?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm writing PHP website.
My code printing table with delete buttons. Javascript listening click and convert userID to send by fetch api:
JavaScript:

```
fetch('remove_user.php', { // i've tryed to add php code to index.php but also remove_user.php does not working
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: 'user_id=' + encodeURIComponent(userId),
      })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error: ', error);
        });
    }
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_POST['user_id'])) {
        $userId = $_POST['user_id'];
        $response = "Received data: " . $userId;
    } else {
       $response = "No data";
    }
 echo $response;
}
```

I want to send value from JavaScript and get it by PHP code. JavaScript start sending after click button on the website.

I tried aJax, REST API; methods: Get, Post or Put.

Also move post check code in main PHP file and new file contain only receive data core.

I need to edit and then save json file after press button.

Could it work or i need find other option to send data, or I make some big mistakes?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Aren't your receiving data? Are you receiving the *wrong* data? Or are you getting errors in the console? Are you sure `'remove_user.php'` is the correct path to your PHP file?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier server return html code of website (in  line `console.log(data)`). When I changed response.text() to response.json() console error:
`Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON`

Comment: According to your code it should either return `"Received data: {user_id}"` or `"No data"` instead of HTML. And the error is pretty straighforward as you can't parse HTML as JSON, because it isn't JSON. The issue still remains unclear.